# function to return the numeric value

Tags: php, string

What would be an elegant way of doing this?

I have this -> "MC0001"  This is the input. It always begins with "MC"
The output I'd be aiming with this input is "MC0002".

So I've created a function that's supposed to return "1" after removing "MC000". I'm going to convert this into an integer later on so I could generate "MC0002" which could go up to "MC9999". To do that, I figured I'd need to loop through the string and count the zeros and so on but I think I'd be making a mess that way.

Anybody has a better idea?

Comment: I didn't get it: What is the input to your function and what is the desired output? Could you give some examples?

Comment: Why don't you use Regular Expressions?

Comment: @webbandit Unnecessary power for such a simple case.

Comment: Hey guys I've updated my question to clarify some thing. I'm not using regex because I have no idea how to use that. BUT I'd love to see it work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php
$string = 'MC0001';
// extract the part succeeding 'MC':
$number_part = substr($string, 2);
// count the digits for later:
$number_digits = strlen($number_part);
// turn it into a number:
$number = (int) $number_part;
// make the next sequence:
$next = 'MC' . str_pad($number + 1, $number_digits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: edit: My bad, sorry. Yes it does give me the output I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just use ltrim to remove any leading chars: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

```
$str = ltrim($str, 'MC0');
$num = intval($str);
```

Comment: Interesting solution. You probably meant `ltrim()` though

Comment: @Jack: yeah, forgot there might be trailing 0's. i'll go ahead and edit my answer.

Comment: My string would be dynamic so I can't know for sure how many trailing zeros I'd encounter.

Comment: @esandrkwn: just edited my answer. use ltrim instead to just remove leading chars and not the trailing ones.

Comment: OP elaborated on the question btw, this answer is not complete

Answer (score 0):

using filter_var might be the best solution.

```
echo filter_var("MC0001", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)."\n";
echo filter_var("MC9999", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

will give you

```
0001
9999
```

These can be cast to int or just used as they are, as PHP will auto-convert anyway if you use them as numbers.

Comment: why downvote? someone is obviously trying to push his own solution^^

Comment: It's not the complete answer, though I didn't vote; in fact, mine was down voted as well even though it's complete.

Answer (score -1):

```
<php
// original number to integer
sscanf( $your_string, 'MC%d', $your_number );
// pad increment to string later on
sprintf( 'MC%04u', $your_number + 1 );
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if there is a better way of parsing a string as an integer when there are leading zero's.

I'd suggest doing the following:
1. Loop through the string ( beginning at location 2 since you don't need the MC part )
2. If you find a number thats bigger than 0, stop, get the substring using your current location and the length of the string minus your current location. Cast to integer, return value.

Answer (score -2):

You can remove the "MC" par by doing a [substring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) operating on the string.

```
$a = "MC0001";
$a = substr($a, 2); //Lengths of "MC"
$number = intval($a); //1
```

Answer (score -2):

```
return intval(str_replace($input, 'MC', ''), 10);
```

Comment: It looks like the question wants `MC` to also be in the output.